# Create a data frame that only contains those tweets with an even ID using a FOR-loop and IF-ELSE

Tags: r, loops

I need to remove the rows with uneven numbers in a dataframe using a for-loop and a if else statement but i don't know how to remove a row if it's meets a condition.

so far i have this:

```
for (i in as.integer(substr(My_columns[,6],18,18))){
  if((i %% 2) == 0) {
  }
  else {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `for` loop here; you can use direct indexing:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
    a = seq(1:20),
    b = seq(1:20))

# Remove rows with uneven numbers
df[-(2 * seq(0, nrow(df) - 1) + 1), ];
#    a  b
#2   2  2
#4   4  4
#6   6  6
#8   8  8
#10 10 10
#12 12 12
#14 14 14
#16 16 16
#18 18 18
#20 20 20
```

Or using the modulo operator:

```
# Keep rows with even numbers
df[1:nrow(df) %% 2 == 0, ];
```

Comment: It would be a roughly similar solution, but OP isn't comparing to row-number, but rather along `My_columns[,6]`

Comment: @thelatemail Ah I missed that bit. This would be easier to do with some sample data. I guess it would be something along the lines of `seq_along(My_columns[, 6])`...

Answer (score 0):

Another one, short and simple.

```
# removes odd rows
> df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),]
```

Or using a for loop (just for your reference):

```
## using a for loop

get_index <- c()
for(i in seq(nrow(df)))
{
    if ( i%%2 == 0)
    {
        get_index <- c(get_index, i)
    }

}
print(df[get_index,])
    a  b
2   2  2
4   4  4
6   6  6
8   8  8
10 10 10
12 12 12
14 14 14
16 16 16
18 18 18
20 20 20
```